# Keep item centered unless pushed

Tags: swift, swiftui

So you have an `HStack` with 3 rectangles.

I want a leading rectangle, a centred one, and a trailing one. And I want the centred one to always be centred.

All of the items can be different widths.

At the moment the closest I can get is this:

[image]

Clearly there is room for the yellow rectangle to move to the centre.

So I want the yellow rectangle taking absolute precedence and always centered, but can't figure it out.

Comment: please add more information, also the code.

Comment: Layout would be perfect for this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing_custom_layouts_with_swiftui

Answer (score 0):

[image]Here is you answer:
You need to add this line after frame which define you rectangle style.

> .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)

```
     HStack{
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.red)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.black)
            .frame(width: 70, height: 100)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity) // for this center element you can comment this line for different alignment, try and check.
        
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.blue)
            .frame(width: 90, height: 100)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
```